# Database Query that takes random data only once

Tags: android, mysql, laravel, api

I'm currently creating API for marketplace in Android using pagination that only load first 20-40 data and using Laravel as back-end.
Is there any query that select a random data but the data only load once? 
for example in mysql:
A
B
C
D
E
F

first api call using inRandomOrder->take(3) :
A, B, E

but in 2nd call :
C,D,F

Edit :
Add inRandomOrder function

Edit more explanation:
I want to fetch random 20 data items(there are 1000 data)..
because i'm using like infinite scroll i don't want load all 1000 data at once(performance issues).. so when i want to load more data i need to call the API again but if you use random order there is a chance that data will load twice or more..

i.e : there are 6 data (A, B, C, D, E , F) first call in random order (A,B,F) but in 2nd call it will load C, D , E

sorry if this is the wrong way to ask.. it's my first time asking on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to save it somewhere how many time your api has been accessed.

I'd do it with sending a counter with your api call instead

Very basic method:

**EDIT: added take**

Route:

```
 Route::get('getdata/{counter}/{take}', ['uses' => 'APIController@getdata']);
```

Controller:

```
public function getdata($counter, $take) {
  Model::skip($counter)->orderByRaw("RAND()")->take($take)->get();
}
```

EDIT: added orderByRaw

So in your api call, add url.com/howmanytoskip/howmanytotake/

In the api call: You have to increase the skip, how many loaded, and decrease the howmanytotake so you get less items per load.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add inRandomOrder function, is there any way to achieve this using random order?

Comment: I tried it using your method but it still returning the same data..

My first call (in id):
9,10,15,7,6

My second call :
9,13,12,15,10

Answer (score 0):

Just make a random search using the [inRandomOrder()](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_inRandomOrder) function.

PD: The OP didn't provide enough information, so I'm gonna use `User` model as an example.

Define your endpoint:

```
/** api.php */

use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

// ...

Route::get('/random-users', [UserController::class, 'getRandom']);
```

Then in your controller:

```
/** UserController.php */

use App\User;

// ...

public function getRandom()
{
    $users = User::inRandomOrder() // <--- randomizing
                        ->take(3) // <--- limiting response to 3 items
                        ->get(); // <--- getting the results

    return response()->json(['users' => $users], 200);
}
```

So now just make a `GET` call to the previously defined endpoint and you'll get your random data:

```
GET http://www.my-website.com/api/random-users
```